# Python: How to import a function which involves another function

Tags: python, python-import

I have a file named **data_extraction** which has two functions `get_data_from_db` and `data_sanity` in which `data_sanity` calls `get_data_from_db`. When i try to import **data_extraction** in a 2nd file i get an error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'data_sanity' from 'data_extraction'

**2nd** file

```
from data_extraction import get_data_from_db
from data_extraction import data_sanity
```

**data_extraction** file

```
def get_data_from_db(db_query, fileName):
    try:  
        (user, password) = creds()

        conn = database_config(user=user, password=password, database="*", port="*", host="*")

        def create_pandas_table(sql_query, database = conn):
            table = read_sql_tmpfile(sql_query, database)
            return table
        import tempfile

        def read_sql_tmpfile(query, conn):
            print("")
            with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
                copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
                   query=query, head="HEADER"
                )
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
                tmpfile.seek(0)
                df = pd.read_csv(tmpfile)

                return df

        conn.close()

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
        print("Error while connecting to the database:", error)

    sub_info.to_csv(f'{fileName}.csv', index=False)
    
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{fileName}.csv')
    
    return df

def data_sanity(model_loan_df):
    db_query = ("""
            select
                *
            from
                fdj.fdknfkdn
            """)          
    raw_loan_df = get_data_from_db(db_query, 'raw_loan_check_data')
    
    return model_loan_df.shape[0] ==  raw_loan_df.shape[0]
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in this directory?

Comment: I don't have a **__init__.py** file.

Comment: Also, you could use a comma to import both functions from the same module

Comment: using a comma doesn't solve the importation error.

Comment: True. I mean, code looks fine as written. I don't see why  the first function could be imported but the second cannot unless there's some spacing issues and you've defined the function after `return df`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, at least it worked on my machine :

```
from data_extraction import *
```

The reason why it does not work may be that they're not in the same directory.

Comment: There are in the same directory. I used ``from data_extraction import *`` which cleared the error but when i called the function ``data_sanity`` i got an error **NameError: name 'data_sanity' is not defined**. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Shadow with this solution, it'd be `data_extraction.data_sanity()`

Comment: I tried ``data_extraction.data_sanity(df)`` but still got the error **NameError: name 'data_sanity' is not defined**

Comment: if you are importing  the python file ,which you had imported data_extraction.data_sanity(df) in, to elsewhere then it may be causing circular import. And thus, it might return Name Error, are you doing anything similar to this case ?